# Override / Disable super-interface method

Tags: java, interface

Consider the interfaces

```
public interface SuperInterface {

  public void execute(Map<String,object> argument);

}

public interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {

  public void execute(Argument extra , Map<String,Object> args);

}
```

Is it possible to completely override `SuperInterfaces.execute` with `SubInterface.execute` even though it has different arguments ?

OR

Am I doing it wrong ? What is the right way to design this spec ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to completely override SuperInterfaces.execute with
>   SubInterface.execute even though it has different arguments ?

If you are allowed to do this, you will breach an agreement.

> Am I doing it wrong ?

Yes, of course.

> What is the right way to design this spec ?

You can't disobey an agreement. So, you can't do like this.

Answer (score 5):

No. When you override a method, it must have the same number and types of arguments. Currently you are *overloading* the `execute` method in `SubInterface`.

You could, however, call `execute(Map<String, Object> args)` from `execute(Argument extra , Map<String, Object> args)` from your implementation of `SubInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SubInterface` should be an `abstract` class.

Then you can have a default and `final` implementation of `one-arg execute` which actually calls `two-arg execute`.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt if i understand your question. 
overriding is redefining method in subclass/interface  with the same arguments (or subtype arguments).
here you are overloading the methods.

being an interface, it wont allow overriding. bcz overriding is a term related to defination, but interface methods doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to @Deprecate(d) the method.

e.g.

```
    public interface SuperInterface {

      public void execute(Map<String,object> argument);

    }

    public interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {

      @Deprecated
      public void execute(Map<String,object> argument);
      public void execute(Argument extra , Map<String,Object> args);

    }
```

This way, you (and others) will be notified about the invalid use of the class method.
If you wait for Java8, I think you will be able to create also a default method for the method in the sub interface and throw an exception when someone executes it (of course the implementing class should not implement the method :)