# Overriding vs. overloading, again

Tags: java, interface

Consider the following `Java` `interface`

```
public interface Script<T> {
    public T execute(Map<String,Object> args); 
}
```

Then we have a

```
public interface SubScript<T> extends Script<T> {
    public T execute(String knownTypeArgument, Map<String,Object> args);
}
```

Here `knownTypeArgument` is always needed by `execute` method in Sub. And in `SubScript` interface the method `public T execute(Map<String,Object> args);` is not needed.

The question I have is that Is it standard / correct practice to define a sub-interface just to add an argument or two ?

Would lead to bad code in implementations If `SubScript` is not defined at all and `knownTypeArgument` is passed in `Map<String,Object> args` ?

PS : 
Both `execute(String knownTypeArgument, Map<String,Object> args);` and `execute(Map<String,Object> args);` should serve exactly the same purpose , Its just that under some circumstances `execute` would need more information.

PPS:
As per stackoverflow rules I am looking for facts/points that I am missing and not discussions.

Comment: The points you are missing have already been pointed out in [the answers to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270889/override-disable-super-interface-method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you write

> And in `SubScript` interface the method `public T execute(Map<String,Object> args);` is not needed.

this does not mean that `execute(Map<String, Object) args)` will go away in `SubScript`. This interface will have *both* methods. They may have the same name but since their signatures are different, they don't interfere with each other.

Every implementation of `SubScript` will have to implement *both* methods. Of course one of these methods could call the other but that is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, any class implementing SubScript would need to implement both

```
public T execute(Map<String,Object> args);
```

and

```
public T execute(String knownTypeArgument, Map<String,Object> args);
```

as two separate overloaded methods, so the above is not a good pattern for your needs.

Maybe create a class to do what your method is designed to do, with an execute() method without arguments, and setter methods to set any required parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces should be used to define the methods that are needed for a given behavior and thus generally end with the "able" suffix, as in draggable or customizable.

As for creating a secondary interface only to add a new method signature, the recommendation is to use method overloading. Java allows the coexistence of several methods with the same name, but different sets of arguments. You could easily have both methods residing in the same class/interface, and call whichever suits the need.

Comment: Which recommendation is it you speak of? And where did you get this "Interfaces should [...] generally end with the 'able'" thing from?

Comment: @arne.b [What is standard for Interface naming in java api](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3939518/896567), java.lang.Appendable, java.lang.Cloneable, java.lang.Comparable, java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Readable, java.lang.Runnable, java.io.Closeable, java.io.Externalizable, java.io.Serializable, ... It's not an absolute rule, but it makes sense...

Comment: You may have missed the "there is no official convention" part in the first sentence, or the link to the official naming conventions. There are certainly many instances of interfaces where an "-able" name makes sense (usually for interfaces that do **not** cover the whole functionality of the implementing class), but a lot where it does not, too (`List`, `Set`, `Observer`). The naming of the OP's class and method seems to suggest the latter.